# Converting a string to number in jupyter

Tags: pandas

**Here is my code:**

```
def value_and_wage_conversion(value):
    if isinstance(value,str):
        if 'M' in out:
            out = float(out.replace('M', ''))*1000000
        elif 'K' in value:
            out = float(out.replace('K', ''))*1000
        return float(out)

fifa_18['Value'] = fifa_18['Value'].apply(lambda x: value_and_wage_conversion(x))
fifa_18['Wage'] = fifa_18['Wage'].apply(lambda x: value_and_wage_conversion(x))
```

Here is the error message:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 7         return float(out)
> 8
> ----> 9 fifa_18['Value'] = fifa_18['Value'].apply(lambda x: value_and_wage_conversion(x))
> 10 fifa_18['Wage'] = fifa_18['Wage'].apply(lambda x: value_and_wage_conversion(x))
>
> c:\users\brain\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py
> in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)    4136
> else:    4137                 values = self.astype(object)._values
> -> 4138                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)    4139     4140         if len(mapped) and
> isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
>
> pandas_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
>
> in (x)
> 7         return float(out)
> 8
> ----> 9 fifa_18['Value'] = fifa_18['Value'].apply(lambda x: value_and_wage_conversion(x))
> 10 fifa_18['Wage'] = fifa_18['Wage'].apply(lambda x: value_and_wage_conversion(x))
>
> in value_and_wage_conversion(value)
> 1 def value_and_wage_conversion(value):
> 2     if isinstance(value,str):
> ----> 3         if 'M' in out:
> 4             out = float(out.replace('M', ''))*1000000
> 5         elif 'K' in value:
>
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'out' referenced before assignment

Comment: Change `if 'M' in out:` to `if 'M' in value:`

Comment: third line: `if 'M' in out:` you want to have `if 'M' in value:`

Furthermore, 
second line: `if isinstance(value,str):` should probably be `if isinstance(value:str):`

Comment: It show this error:   File "<ipython-input-53-efd27ec38096>", line 2
    if isinstance(value:str):
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there but you need to fix your function

For example

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate a random sample
values = ['10M', '10K', 10.5, '200M', '200K', 200]
size = 100
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Value': np.random.choice(values, size),
    'Wage': np.random.choice(values, size),
})

print(df)

   Value  Wage
0    200   200
1   200M  200M
2   200K   200
3    10M   10M
4    10K  200M
..   ...   ...
95  200K   200
96   200  200M
97  10.5  200K
98  200K  10.5
99  200M   10M

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Define function and apply

```py
def value_and_wage_conversion(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        if 'M' in value:
            value = float(value.replace('M', ''))*1000000
        elif 'K' in value:
            value = float(value.replace('K', ''))*1000
        return float(value)

df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x: value_and_wage_conversion(x))
df['Wage'] = df['Wage'].apply(lambda x: value_and_wage_conversion(x))

print(df)

          Value         Wage
0         200.0        200.0
1   200000000.0  200000000.0
2      200000.0        200.0
3    10000000.0   10000000.0
4       10000.0  200000000.0
..          ...          ...
95     200000.0        200.0
96        200.0  200000000.0
97         10.5     200000.0
98     200000.0         10.5
99  200000000.0   10000000.0

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

and check

```py
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   Value   100 non-null    float64
 1   Wage    100 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 1.7 KB
```

Comment: see what i have: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-9f03d81abc3d> in <module>
      7         return float(value)
      8 
----> 9 fifa_2018['ValueNum'] = fifa_2018['Value'].apply(lambda x: value_and_wage_conversion(x))
     10 fifa_2018['WageNum'] = fifa_2018['Wage'].apply(lambda x: value_and_wage_conversion(x))
     11 print(fifa_2018)

NameError: name 'fifa_2018' is not defined

Comment: Isn't `fifa_18` the name of your DataFrame? You may double check if you used the correct DataFrame name.

Comment: def value_and_wage_conversion(value):
    if isinstance(value,str):
        if 'M' in value:
            value = float(value.replace('M', ''))*1000000
        elif 'K' in value:
            value = float(value.replace('K', ''))*1000
        return float(value)

fifa_18['ValueNum'] = fifa_18['Value'].apply(lambda x: value_and_wage_conversion(x))
fifa_18['WageNum'] = fifa_18['Wage'].apply(lambda x: value_and_wage_conversion(x))

Comment: I can't see indentations and new lines written in this way. The `def` ends at `return` line, right?

Comment: There are indentations

Comment: I want to convert value and wage from string to integer dtype, i have my data in 13M, 15K format,  i want to convert them into 13000000 and 15000 respectively.

Comment: Please try to apply the function I wrote in the answer